# JS is not working: Sublime 3 editor- Var main = function() -the = is not "activating" (Function-Newbie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, var

This is my JS and HTML. The first line of JS is not working. In Sublime my = should turn red as the other do but this first one does not and I have no idea why. I am a function newbie. Please let me know what you think! Thank you

```
      var main = function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event){
        var $input = $(event.target).find('input');
        var comment = $input.val();

        if (comment != ""){
            var html = $('<li>').text(comment);
            html.prependTo('#comments')
            $inputs.val("");

            }
            return false;
        });


    }

    $(document).ready(main);


    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' />
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
        </head>
        <body>
            <header class="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <h1>Gossipz</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="main">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="form">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10">
                                <input id="comment" type="text" placeholder="share your thoughts">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">post</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="comments" id"comments">
                        <li> No Honey, I don't gossip... I <b>truth</b>!</li>
                        <li> OMG...She said <big>what</big> girl?!?</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this code in plunker but could not replicate the problem.Below is an issue which you may look.

1)`<ul class="comments" id"comments">` It is typo it should be

If your sublime text is configured with `jsLint/jsHint` you can hover on the issue to see the error at the bottom.

You can check the working of your code here in this [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/lulFM3Nd0KF9JZTuiS1F?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the correction. I updated that and check PLUNKER (love this by the way). It totally works there great. When I tried it in CHROME or IE my post won't stay; the post immediately disappeared after posting. ...... but in PLUNKER or CSSDeck.com/labs when testing,  it worked perfectly!! What do you think?